# How to query binance margin account for unique symbol balance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, binance

I am currently able to query my margin account successfully using this code from python-binance v0.7.5:

```
client.get_margin_account()
```

It returns this list of lists of margin balances and information which lists all symbols on the exchange, starting from highest to lowest balance:

```
  {'tradeEnabled': True,
 'transferEnabled': True,
 'borrowEnabled': True,
 'marginLevel': '999.00000000',
 'totalAssetOfBtc': '0.00000000',
 'totalLiabilityOfBtc': '0.00000000',
 'totalNetAssetOfBtc': '0.00000000',
 'userAssets': [{'asset': 'BTC',
   'free': '0.00000000',
   'locked': '0.00000000',
   'borrowed': '0.00000000',
   'interest': '0.00000000',
   'netAsset': '0.00000000'},
  {'asset': 'ETH',
   'free': '0.00000000',
   'locked': '0.00000000',
   'borrowed': '0.00000000',
   'interest': '0.00000000',
   'netAsset': '0.00000000'}]}
```

I can query specific assets as follows:

```
client.get_margin_account()['userAssets'][0]['free']
```

But when I use this code:

```
client.get_margin_account()['userAssets']['btc']['free']
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How am I able to query specific symbols in my account without specifying index location?

Comment: did you find a way to query isolated margin account?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: use `next()`:

```
data = {'tradeEnabled': True,
 'transferEnabled': True,
 'borrowEnabled': True,
 'marginLevel': '999.00000000',
 'totalAssetOfBtc': '0.00000000',
 'totalLiabilityOfBtc': '0.00000000',
 'totalNetAssetOfBtc': '0.00000000',
 'userAssets': [{'asset': 'BTC',
   'free': '0.00000000',
   'locked': '0.00000000',
   'borrowed': '0.00000000',
   'interest': '0.00000000',
   'netAsset': '0.00000000'},
  {'asset': 'ETH',
   'free': '0.00000000',
   'locked': '0.00000000',
   'borrowed': '0.00000000',
   'interest': '0.00000000',
   'netAsset': '0.00000000'}]}


print( next(d for d in data['userAssets'] if d['asset'] == 'BTC')['free'] )
```

---

Option 2: Convert userAssets to dictionary:

```
ua = {d['asset']: d for d in data['userAssets']}
print(ua['BTC']['free'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, with option 1 when my code is: `next(x for x in client.get_margin_account['userAssets'] if x['asset'] == 'BTC')['free']` i get an error: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Mitch You probably meant `client.get_margin_account('userAssets')`, not `['userAssets']`

Comment: updated brackets in code and now get: `TypeError: get_margin_account() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: @Mitch Look, how `get_margin_account()` method is defined. From the error message it needs 1 argument, but you supplied 2.

Comment: This keep returns `0` for me even I have a opened postion in the margin account not sure why